# Is there any way for a function to be unbounded in a neighborhood of $a$ besides division by $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The standard examples of function that are unbounded in a neighborhood of $a$ are functions of the $\frac{1}{x-a}$ variety, or $\tan(x)$, which is just division by $0$ but hidden a bit better.

Are there other examples of functions that are unbounded in a neighborhood of a point without any division by 0?

Comment: There are functions unbounded in every neighborhood of every point. They will not be of this form.

Comment: I would actually love to see an example of one, do they exist from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ as a metric space or do we need a more pathological example?

Comment: I gave a few examples  below with brief proofs.

Comment: @Math Check out [Conways base-13-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function). In the end, every unbounded function is the (local) reciprocal of a function which tends to zero where the original function tends to infinity. However, there are functions where the reciprocal is not much better behaved than the function itself (see link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity suppose that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=+\infty$, $f(x)\ne0$ if $x\ne0$. Let
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}1/f(x) & x\ne0,\\0 &x=0.\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)},\quad x\ne0.
$$
We see that we can always with any infinite limit as division by $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\ln\lvert x\rvert$ for $a=0$ comes to mind.

Comment: the definition of $\ln(x)$ I learned was the integral of 1/t from 1 to x, which is really division by 0 but hidden

Comment: @math Like it is hidden in the definition of the continuous function $$\sqrt{\lvert x\rvert}=\lim_{y\to x}\exp\int_0^{\lvert y\rvert}\frac{1}{2t}\,dt\qquad?$$

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't say continuous, here is one example:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0\text{ if }x\text{ is irrational}\\q\text{ if }x=\frac{p}{q}\text{ in lowest terms}\end{cases}$$

For a continuous, piecewise defined function, consider linearly interpolating between the points $(\tfrac{1}{n},n)$ for $n=1,2,\dots$

Answer (score 0):

One way to build a fairly wild unbounded function is through measure theory. Let $f(t) = t^{-1/2}\cdot \chi_{(0,1)}.$ Let $q_1,q_2, \dots$ be the rationals. Then the function

$$g(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}f(t-q_n)$$

is is finite a.e., and because $g$ blows up at each $q_n,$ $g$ is unbounded on every nonempty open subinterval of $\mathbb R.$

Here is a more ambitious example. Claim: There exists a function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R $ such that $f(I) =\mathbb R$ for every nonempty open subinterval $I$ of $\mathbb R.$

Proof: Let $I_1,I_2, \dots$ be the open subintervals of $\mathbb R$ with rational end points. We can inductively choose pairwise disjoint Cantor sets $K_1,K_2,\dots$ such that $K_n\subset I_n$ for each $n.$

Now each $K_n$ has the cardinality of $\mathbb R.$ Hence for each $n$ there is a bijection $f_n: K_n \to \mathbb R.$ Define $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by setting $f= f_n$ on each $K_n,$ $f=0$ everywhere else. (Since the $K_n$ are pairwise disjoint, this map is well defined.)

Let $I$ be a nonempty open subinterval of $\mathbb R.$ Then $I$ contains some $I_n.$ Hence it contains $K_n.$ Thus $f((a,b))$ contains $f(K_n) =  f_n(K_n) = \mathbb R.$ Thus the claim is proved.